# Web API: Authorization and Dependency Injection

Tags: asp.net, .net, authentication, dependency-injection, asp.net-web-api

Is there a sample solution or example how I do authorization/authentication with DI in the ASP.NET Web API?

Comment: Do you mean ASP.NET web forms or ASP.NET MVC? IMHO it would be much easier to use DI in the latter.

Comment: I mean ASP.NET MVC 4 Web API. Web API is microsoft's new REST API framework.

Comment: Your question is vaque. What do you want to know about authorization and authentication with DI? This question might not be a good fit foor Stackoverflow.

Comment: I want to know if there is a best practise example or solution. There always simple examples for DI **or** authentication, but nothing which explains both in collaboration.